# Prevent qtip from showing

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, tooltip

How can I **prevent** `qtip` from showing on `grid` `cell`s with "large" `data` that does not fit inside its width? (on **ExtJS 6.5.2 - Modern Toolkit**)

**Example**

Add this to a sencha fiddle:

```
 Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { 'name': 'Lisaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244" },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254" }
    ]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    title: 'Simpsons',

    store: store,

    columns: [
        { 
            text: 'Name',  
            dataIndex: 'name', 
            minWidth: 200, 
            //flex: 1,
            //cellWrap: true,
            cell: {
                bodyStyle: {
                    whiteSpace: 'normal'
                }
            }
        },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 2, minWidth: 250 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', flex: 1,  minWidth: 120 }
    ],

    //height: 200,
    //layout: 'fit',
    fullscreen: true
    });
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Grid without tooltip**

Default wrapping behaviour but no tooltip, demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29ii

**Grid with wrapping capabilities**

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29if

In short you need to set these rules to wrap content:

```
white-space: normal;
word-break: break-word;
```

And set grid's "variableHeights" to true: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#cfg-variableHeights

Note: in the fiddle the CSS rules are applied using grid's "cls" config param, and styles are placed inside index.html

Comment: Marco is there a way to make it work even when the `cell`'s value is html? (`renderer` only works with `Ext.grid.cell.Cell`)

Comment: I changed store's data and the html is working as expected: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29ii

Comment: I know. I just use `renderer` to create html in one case. Thanks for your effort Marco.